# Using a redux store with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, react-navigation

I'm trying to add a redux store to my react-native app, using expo.

The App looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

// Persistent storage
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';
import BoardScreen from './BoardScreen';
import BoardDetailsScreen from './BoardDetailsScreen';
import CardDetailsScreen from './CardDetailsScreen';

// Store
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import store from './store/store';
import { setNCServer, setToken } from './store/actions';


// For creating an URL handler to retrieve the device token
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

// Create Stack navigator
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

// Application
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    // Retrieve token from storage if available
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(token => {
      this.props.state.setToken(token)  
    })

    // Register handler to catch Nextcloud's redirect after successfull login
    Linking.addEventListener('url', (url) => {this.handleRedirect(url)})
  }

  // Function to retrieve the device's token and save it after user logged in
  handleRedirect = async (url) => {
    if (url.url.startsWith('nc://login/server')) {
      try {
        token = url.url.substring(url.url.lastIndexOf(':'))
        console.log('Persisting token', token)
        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);  
        this.props.state.setToken(token)
      } catch (e) {
        // TODO
      } 
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.token === null) {
      // No token is stored yet, we need to get one
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
      ) 
    } else {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="AllBoard" component={BoardScreen} options={{title: 'All boards'}} />
              <Stack.Screen name="BoardDetails" component={BoardDetailsScreen} options={{title: 'Board details'}} />
              <Stack.Screen name="CardDetails" component={CardDetailsScreen} options={{title: 'Card details'}} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
      )
    }
  }
}

// Initialise store
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators({
    setNCServer,
    setToken,
  }, dispatch)
);
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
};
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default connector(App);
```

Problem: When I start the application I'm getting the infamous error "Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)"".

I've racked my head for hours on this problem and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `connect` on components which are *inside* of your Redux `Provider` component.  Right now your `Provider` is inside of `App` so you cannot use `connect` on `App`.  You need to move the `Provider` up a level.

I'm seeing a bunch of other issues here as well: `this.props.state.setToken(token)` should be `this.props.setToken(token)` and `this.state.token` should be `this.props.state.token` -- but really you should be using `mapStateToProps` to just select the token and not return the whole state!

You might find the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks to be more intuitive.

`url.url` is very confusingly named.  Really it's an event with a property `url` so you should call it `e` or `event`.  But you can also destructure it as `({url})` instead of `(e)` and `e.url`.

```
// Application contents
class AppNavigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Retrieve token from storage if available
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((token) => {
      this.props.setToken(token);
    });

    // Register handler to catch Nextcloud's redirect after successfull login
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleRedirect);
  }

  // Function to retrieve the device's token and save it after user logged in
  handleRedirect = async ({ url }) => {
    if (url.startsWith('nc://login/server')) {
      try {
        const token = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(':'));
        console.log('Persisting token', token);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
        this.props.setToken(token);
      } catch (e) {
        // TODO
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.token === null) {
      // No token is stored yet, we need to get one
      return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
      );
    } else {
      return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="AllBoard"
                component={BoardScreen}
                options={{ title: 'All boards' }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="BoardDetails"
                component={BoardDetailsScreen}
                options={{ title: 'Board details' }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="CardDetails"
                component={CardDetailsScreen}
                options={{ title: 'Card details' }}
              />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
  }
}

// Can just be an object of functions to bind - creates props `setNCServer` and `setToken`
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setNCServer,
  setToken,
};

// Creates a prop `token` with the token from state
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    token: state.token,
  };
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const ConnectedNavigation = connector(AppNavigation);

// use the connected component inside a redux Provider
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedNavigation />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi,

I'd figured it out about 24h ago.

Thanks for your answer and remarks anyway: I still have a lot to learn about react-native ;-)